# Fix java callable stored procedure to use the spring data source properties

Tags: java, sql

I am writing a spring boot application and I am trying to create a callable stored procedure, however I am having issues with the connection. I originally have the connection set up using Hibernate and JPA, by incorporating the `spring.datasource` in my `application.properties` file. So I am looking for a way to ignore setting up the connection and have it automatically call the `application.propeties` file for when it needs to make the call.

**Application Properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://server\\RRSHRD01;databaseName=db_name
spring.datasource.username=User
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.databasename=db_nam,e
spring.datasource.databaseschema=APD
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
```

**Java code:**

```
Connection con = null; 
        try { 

            String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://server\\\\RRSHRD01;databaseName=dn_name"; 
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "User", "password"); 
            System.out.println("Success");
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 

            }
```

So above is the code I want to replace, instead of calling the connection I want it to automatically look and retrieve it from my application properties. I want to do this because when I do it the normal way the session always times out.

Comment: Why are you trying to retrieve the connection this way, since you have hibernate as dependency you can use the entityManager.

Comment: @altarbza Correct me if I am wrong but I want to do a callable for my stored procedure and I though I had to set it up like this in order to do it. Right?

Comment: There are better ways to retrieve the connection with hibernate. You can use the `unwrap` method from entityManager to retrieve the session, then with the session you can use the method doWork. Example:
https://justonedeveloper.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/convert-hibernate-session-to-jdbc-connection/